# Javascript: How to access public member variables when creating object with immediate invocation

Tags: javascript, scope

I can use immediate invocation to create an object with methods that have access to private members.

```
var myObj = (function () {
  // Private member variables
  var privateX;

  function setPropX (value) {
    privateX = value;
  }

  function getPropX () {
    return privateX;
  }

  function init() {
    privateX = "Initial value privateX";
  }

  init();

  // Public API
  return {
    // Methods
    "setPropX": setPropX,
    "getPropX": getPropX
  };
}());
```

After this I can work with the object just fine using the public API but my private members are correctly hidden:

```
myObj.setPropX("Hello world");
alert(myObj.getPropX());           // --> Hello world
alert(myObj.privateX);             // --> Undefined
```

Now for my question:

Is it possible to add public properties to the object which can be accessed both by the caller and from within my code? They would then be used like this:

```
myObj.publicY = "ABC";
myObj.sayPublicY();           // Should alert --> ABC
```

I tried to do it like this:

```
var myObj = (function () {
  // Private member variables
  var self = this;
  var privateX;

  function setPropX (value) {
    privateX = value;
  }

  function getPropX () {
    return privateX;
  }

  function sayPublicY () {
    alert(self.publicY);
  }

  function init() {
    privateX = "Initial value privateX";
    self.publicY = "Initial value publicY";
  }

  init();

  // Public API
  return {
    // Methods
    "setPropX": setPropX,
    "getPropX": getPropX,
    "sayPublicY": sayPublicY
  };
}());
```

I thought this would work but it doesn't. The `self`reference saved in the closure is referencing the `window` object. Why does it not reference `myObj` ?

I must be missing something obvious but I couldn't find anything on Google or SO.

What is the correct way to do this?

**EDIT: Added details of init() method which is still not working**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because inside your closure `this` (`var self = this;`) equals the `window` rather than the instance you've created. This declaration of `self` is useless; as it'll *always* equal `window`, and should be removed (and not used).

The resolution of `this` is delayed until execution time, however because you're specifically using `self` instead of `this`, you're always using `window`. Change `self` to `this` inside `sayPublicY`, and it'll work.

The use of an `init` function using this form of construction is not valid. The `constructor`  in this code is the following few lines:

```
return {
  // Methods
  "setPropX": setPropX,
  "getPropX": getPropX,
  "sayPublicY": sayPublicY
};
```

Up until those few lines, you do not have an instance of `myObj`. You merely have the definitions and declarations of private variables/ methods which *could* be added to the `myObj` object. The return statement constructs your `myObj`, and assigns it the methosd `setPropX`, `getPropX` and `sayPublicY`. This is also where you should add your `publicY` attribute:

```
return {
  // Methods
  "setPropX": setPropX,
  "getPropX": getPropX,
  "sayPublicY": sayPublicY,
  "publicY": "Initial Value of Public Y"
};
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, up to a point. Referencing `this` in the `sayPublicY()` method now works correctly. I have edited my question to include my `init()` function. This still does not work. Using `this` or `self` in the `init()` function both give me a reference to the `window` object. How do I reference my public property from my `init()` function.

Comment: Ah... of course (light bulb goes on). Great explanation; it's all about that realisation that the { ... } is the constructor. Thanks for your help